# Unable to define runtime parameters with secret in azure YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to create a secret runtime parameter as described in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/runtime-parameters.md#syntax). But getting the below error.

`Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 12, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'secret'`

Code:

`parameters:
- name: app
  type: string
  values:
  - App1
  - App2
- name: mySecret
  type: string
  secret: true`

I have raised the same in 
[Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1035297/unable-to-define-secret-run-time-parameters.html?childToView=1036380#comment-1036380) portal as well. Please let me know if there is any way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to define runtime parameters with secret in azure YAML

Indeed, I could also reproduced this issue on my side. That because that document is a **Design Docs**.

You could check the [state of that doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/tree/master/design#azure-pipelines-yaml---design-docs):

[image]

> The design docs within this repo are created at different times during
>   the development of Azure Pipelines, to support collaborative
>   contributions to the design process. Designs documents are for,
>
> - **features considered for implementation but never implemented**
> - already implemented features
> - **future ideas for features**
>
> **The design docs in this repo may not represent the current state of an Azure Pipelines feature**.

**Obviously**, this is a function that has **not yet been implemented**. That the reason why you get that error. You can expect it to come, I believe it will meet us soon.

Hope this helps.